# rewrite single occurence in ltac

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

How can I invoke `rewrite` in ltac to only rewrite one occurrence? I think coq's documentation mentions something about `rewrite at` but I haven't been able to actually use it in practice and there are no examples.

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
Definition f (a b: nat): nat.
Admitted.

Theorem theorem1: forall a b: nat, f a b = 4.
Admitted.

Theorem theorem2: forall (a b: nat), (f a b) + (f a b) = 8.
Proof.
intros a b.
(*
my goal here is f a b + f a b = 8
I want to only rewrite the first f a b
The following tactic call doesn't work
*)
rewrite -> theorem1 at 1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `rewrite at` variant of the tactic, which as the manual specifies is always performed via setoid rewriting (see https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic121).

Another possibility to have finer control over your rewriting rules is to assert the general shape of your desired rewrite (which here one would prove via `theorem1`), then perform a focused rewrite with the new hypothesis.

This works without resort to any libraries:

```
intros a b.
assert (H: f a b + f a b = 4 + f a b) by (rewrite theorem1; reflexivity).
rewrite H.
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

When I try `rewrite -> theorem1 at 1.` as you suggest, I get the
following error message:

```
Error: Tactic failure: Setoid library not loaded.
```

So, as a reaction, I restarted your script, including the following command
at the very beginning.

```
Require Import Setoid.
```

And now, it works (I am testing with coq 8.6).

Answer (score 3):

There are several options, one of them was pointed out by @Yves.

Another option is to use the `pattern` tactic:

```
pattern (f a b) at 1.
rewrite theorem1.
```

The trick here is in fact that `pattern (f a b) at 1.` turns the goal

```
f a b + f a b = 8
```

into

```
(fun n : nat => n + f a b = 8) (f a b)
```

Basically, it beta-expands your goal, abstracting on the first occurrence of `f a b`. Also, normally `rewrite` won't rewrite under binders (e.g. lambdas), because if it did, you'd be able to go from let's say `fun x => x + 0` to `fun x => x`, which are not equal in vanilla Coq.

Then `rewrite theorem1.` rewrites the argument `(f a b)` to `4` and simplifies a bit (it does beta-reduction), hence you obtain `4 + f a b = 8`.

Side note: you can also use the `replace` tactic like so:

```
replace (f a b + f a b) with (4 + f a b) by now rewrite theorem1.
```